Worst running time cases for merging two sorted arrays of size n and m
I was doing a problem and I am getting a bit confused on the worst cases for using merge sort on two arrays of lengths n and m. The question already says that they are sorted and I am assuming they are equal sizes respectively.
But I am having trouble deciding on if the worst case of running tome is n*m or the max(n, m). There can be more than one answer but I'm just struggling on whether the two would be correct with my understanding.
I looked through my notes, and since the two are already sorted, most of the problems I am thinking of seem to be just on whether it would be n + m or something else.

O(n + m) is right.

The answer would be m+n.
To better understand, take this example: m =[1,2,3,4] and n=[5,6,7]. In this case, it doesn't matter whether the size of len(m) > len(n) or vice versa, because to merge, you will have to completely iterate m and then iterate n.

The number of moves for merging into a third array is always m+n.  The maximum number of compares is m+n-1. The minimum number of compares is min(m,n) .

So because you have to find the minimum number of compares to merge, then iterate through both you have to add the two and subtract 1? Or am I missing something?

@srises723 - assume that m is smaller than n and that all of the elements in the m array are smaller than the first element of the n array. In this case, there are m compares, and then since the m array is done, then the n elements are copied without doing any further compares. The maximum number of compares occurs when the merging results in just 1 element left in the m and n array, a final compare is done, and the remaining element copied for a total of m+n-1 compares.
